# Mailing list replies to go only to the sender, except when reply-all is used

Tags: php, list, phpmailer, mailing, mailman

I am working on a PHP based mailing list using PHPmailer.

Currently I have implemented two options for answers to mailing list posts: reply to sender only Vs reply to list. This basically controls which address is inserted in the Reply-To field.

I want to create the behaviour which my users know from Mailman, here an example:

SenderA posts a message:

> From: senderA@foo.bar
>
> To: list@foo.bar

The mailing list forwards it to all recipients, e.g. here to RecipientA:

> From: senderA@foo.bar
>
> To: recipientA@foo.bar
>
> CC: list@foo.bar

Now RecipientA replies to the post and the reply looks like that:

> From: recipientA@foo.bar
>
> To: senderA@foo.bar

The other option RecipientA has is posting the reply to the whole mailing by choosing "reply to all" in the mail client which looks like that in the reply:

> From: recipientA@foo.bar
>
> To: senderA@foo.bar
>
> CC: list@foo.bar

When I would decide to set the mailing list's address in the CC field for all forwarded mails:

- Does that mean the mail comes back to the mailing list 100 times when I send out the mail to 100 subscribers (-> it would cost quite a lot of performance to retrieve, check and drop that duplicate mails)
- Can I include a certain header so that the mail to the CC'd mailing list is not send 100 times? How can I tell the mail server(s) to not do that?

Or:

- Is there an alternative way to allow the users to decide to reply to the sender or to the whole list?

Comment: As far as i know, in phpmailer, you can set reply-to ( http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html ): 

At the time this tutorial was written, here is a list of features currently available:

    Can send emails with multiple TOs, CCs, BCCs and REPLY-TOs

Comment: That's right, that's what I am doing already.
But there is nothing like a Reply-CC, which would be the perfect match.

Comment: You could simulate from the script that sends the email...add to reply-to only the cc addresses...make some kind of selector asking the user who should the recepient be able to reply to...eventually add a checkbox list with all the addresses so he can check who to add in reply-to...

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem - I have no influence on the way the users see the mails -> the can use all sorts of mail clients
The only way I see the user has a chance for doing this choice is by choosing reply Vs reply-to-all in his mail client.

And that brings the problem that the mailing list account gets spammed with it's own mails.

Comment: What if I supply a header field Message-ID? From Wikipedia: "Message-ID: Also an automatically generated field; used to prevent multiple delivery and for reference in In-Reply-To [...]"

When I supply the Message-ID in my program is it ensured that the mail sever does not create a new one? Does that prevent the target mail server from working 1000 times with the same message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - most email clients will treat replying to mailing list emails as desired when the following conditions are met for the outgoing mailing list emails:

- The emails come with the standard mailing list headers according to [RFC 2369](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2369.html), you definitely need *List-Post* with something like `<mailto:list@foo.bar>`
- For replies only to the sender you either need a correct set *From* header field (must be the email of the sender, `recipientA@foo.bar` in the example) or the *Reply-To* header field in case you cannot change the *From* field

This is slightly different from the Mailman approach but it works very well and you can be sure that your server does not have to deal with unwanted duplicates